# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently started using Android Studio instead of using Eclipse.
I used Android Studio to import and migrate the Eclipse project into Android Studio. If i build the project with AS and download it to a device it works fine.

The problem is if a device already has the previous version of the app installed on it (which was build by Eclipse), it will not install or even open up. I get the following Exception.

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920)
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6195)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2699)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2161)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6318)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6096)
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170)
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3986)
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                             at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                             at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
                                             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2404) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264) 
                                             at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614) 
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221) 
                                             at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:920) 
                                             at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:6195) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2699) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2161) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:6318) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:6096) 
                                             at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:170) 
                                             at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3986) 
                                             at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
                                          Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

.

The above exception seemed to happen after i updated Android Studio build and gradle. Everything worked ok until then.

The Eclipse set up was:
Android SDK Build-Tools 23.0.3

project target = Google Inc.:Google APIs:22

The Current Android Studio is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionName "4.0.1"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "RR3v$versionName")
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/core.jar')
    compile files('libs/ftp4j-1.7.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/ndeftools-1.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

.

Does anyone know why the update will not install?
My apk update will not even open via the package installer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like the installer failed because it was unable to find a class. Did you refactor your code and deleted/moved/renamed classes on the newer version?

Comment: You may also want to see if you got an installation error code and look at the PackageManager class for the meaning of it. For example -7 means that the app cannot be updated due to a signature conflict.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to resolve this? I'm having the same issue on Samsung A5 with my app.

Comment: It may be related to proguard as I see  minifyEnabled true in your script

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that a version downgrade is attempted (which is not allowed). It seems that your Eclipse project set the version code differently than AndroidStudio does now.

Set the versionCode manually to the same or a higher number than your Eclipse build (you can check the old code in the AndroidManifest) by adding this to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1234
    ...
    }
}
```

Apart from that, you can always install with the "allow downgrade" flag using adb:

```
adb install -r -d myApk.apk
```

`-r` allows to install an already existing app

`-d` allows a version downgrade

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, but I wonder if your answer is compatible with the error message "ClassNotFoundException: com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFlowAnalytics"

Comment: I don't have it available any more but I am almost (:-) ) sure that I had the exact same callstack and solved it with this.

Comment: I don't know why you got a down vote but this actually solved my problem. For that you get an upvote from me (:-))